# Truncated normal with a given mode

Tags: r, random, distribution, sample, normal-distribution

I would like to generate a random truncated normal distribution with the following properties.

1. lower bound= 3
2. higher bond= 5
3. using a fixed set of values at the first digit(3.0,3.1,3.2,...,4.9,5.0)
4. With mode=3
5. the probability of 5 occurring should be 50% of the probability of 3 occurring.

I was able to deal with the first 3 steps but I am struggling to find a way to set mode=3 and to establish a fixed relationship on the occurrence of the higher and lower bound.

```
library(truncnorm)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
dist<- as.data.frame(list(truncnorm=round(rtruncnorm(10000, a=3, b=5, mean=3.3, sd=1),1)))
ggplot(dist,aes(x=truncnorm))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 40)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As you can see I can create truncated normal with the desired boundaries.
The problem with this distribution are two.

- First I want `truncnorm==3.0` to be the mode (i.e. most frequent value of my distribution, while in this case the mode is `truncnorm==3.2`
- Second I want the count of 5.0 values to be 50% of the 3.0 values. For example, if I generated a distribution with 800 observations with `truncnorm=3.0`, there should be approximately 400 observations with `truncnorm=5.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, all your requirements are achievable using a truncated normal distribution.

Let `low = 3` and `high = 5`.

Simply evaluate the density (at discrete points such as 3.0, 3.1, ..., 4.9, 5.0) of a normal distribution with mean `low` and standard deviation `sqrt(2)*(high-low)/(2*sqrt(ln(2))`.

This standard deviation is found by taking the following function proportional to a normal density with mean 0 and standard deviation `z`:

```
 f(x) = exp(-(x-0)**2/(2*z**2))
```

Since f(0) = 1, we must find the necessary standard deviation `z` such that `f(x) = 1/2`. The solution is:

```
 g(x) = sqrt(2)*x/(2*sqrt(ln(2))
```

And plugging `high-low` into `x` leads to the final standard deviation given above.